# Rails use array in HAML + Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, haml

Hello I have the following examples, I can't figure out how to make it work in html.haml.

Example 1 ( working):

```
# In html.erb file
<% @my_array = ['1, '2'] %>

<script>
  window.running_cycler = new MyAwesomeClass({
    custom_data: <%= raw @my_array %>
  });
</script>
```

Example 2 ( not working )

```
# In html.haml file
- @my_array = ['1', '2']

:javascript
  window.running_cycler = new MyAwesomeClass({
    custom_data: "#{raw @my_array}" 
    # or 
    # custom_data: "#{@my_array}"
  })
```

This is the browser error it throws.
[image]
How can I make it work in html.haml file?? It seems like raw is not working at all.
If I don't use 'raw' then the format it gets converted is:

```
"[&quot;1&quot;, &quot;8&quot;]"
```

[image]

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use single quotes and `raw`:

```
- @my_array = ['1', '2']

:javascript
  window.running_cycler = { 'custom_data': '#{raw @my_array}' }
  console.log(JSON.parse(window.running_cycler.custom_data).length)
  // 2
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. It works with JSON.parse('#{raw @my_array}'). However I'm confused that I have to explicitly call JSON.pase while,Coffeescript should do that.

Comment: Apparently,  `window.running_cycler = { custom_data: #{raw @my_array} }` is working as well.